# hybrid application not working when i choose the "later" option in custom direct update

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a hybrid application with IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.

I am facing an issue with custom direct update, where I have two options:  to update now or later. When I choose to update the application, everything is working fine. But when i choose "later", I am unable to login (adapter service unable to communicate with the MobileFirst Server).

```
wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function(directUpdateData, directUpdateContext) {
            // custom WL.SimpleDialog for Direct Update
            var customDialogTitle = 'Update Available';
            var customDialogMessage = 'Update your application to get new features';
            var customButtonText1 = 'Update Application';
            var customButtonText2 = 'Not Now';
            WL.SimpleDialog.show(customDialogTitle, customDialogMessage,
                [{
                    text : customButtonText1,
                    handler : function() {
                        directUpdateContext.start();                        
                    }
                },
                {
                    text : customButtonText2,
                    handler : function() {
                        wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
                    }
                }]
            );
};
```

**authenticationConfig.xml**

```
<customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
    <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
</customSecurityTest>           

<customSecurityTest name="AuthSecurityTest">
    <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="AuthRealm"/>
</customSecurityTest>  

<customSecurityTest name="xssSecurity">
    <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
</customSecurityTest>
```

```
 <realm loginModule="AuthLoginModule" name="AuthRealm">         <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
    <parameter name="login-function" value="LoginAdapter.onAuthRequired"/>
    <parameter name="logout-function" value="LoginAdapter.onLogout"/>
</realm>

<realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
</realm>

<realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
</realm>
```

```
 <loginModule name="AuthLoginModule">
      <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
</loginModule>

<loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="3600">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
</loginModule>

<loginModule name="requireLogin" expirationInSeconds="3600">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
</loginModule>

<loginModule name="rejectAll" expirationInSeconds="3600">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
</loginModule>
```

**application-descriptor**

```
<iphone bundleId="" version="1.0">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        </security>
    </iphone>
    <userIdentityRealms/>
    <accessTokenExpiration>3600</accessTokenExpiration>
    <android version="1.0">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
            <publicSigningKey/>
            <packageName/>
        </security>
    </android>
    <ipad bundleId="" version="1.0">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        </security>
    </ipad>
    <windowsPhone8 version="1.0">
        <uuid>dfae1768-838f-4fda-acc8-11b201cae4d0</uuid>
    </windowsPhone8>
    <mobileWebApp cacheManifest="no-use" securityTest="xssSecurity" xFrameOptions="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    <windows8 version="1.0">
        <description>windows8 is the identifier Windows 8 Universal desktop/tablet Universal app.  Use the Package family name from the package.appxmanifest file as the value for the packageName tag</description>
        <uuid>edff315b-76ed-4bdb-b710-f44462081793</uuid>
    </windows8>
    <windowsphoneuniversal version="1.0">
        <description>windowsphoneuniversal is the identifier for Windows Phone Universal.  Use the Package family name from the package.appxmanifest file as the value for the packageName tag</description>
        <uuid>46bbad67-8f1a-4c5a-8d1a-5400ef36a787</uuid>
    </windowsphoneuniversal>
```

Comment: Can you add some logs? What happens after you click "later"? What error do you get?

Comment: Also add your application-descriptor.xml and authenticationConfig.xml

Comment: @IdanAdar I cannot see any error in console or any where, what happens when I click on "later" is I am getting the same update available dialog again. I cannot even see the logs I have written in the adapter being printed in the MobileFirst Console.

Comment: @IdanAdar How can I share my application-descriptor and authenticationConfig files here?

Comment: Click the edit button in the question and paste the text.

Comment: @IdanAdar : added my config and descriptor files, please check

Comment: Which environment fails?

Comment: We checked in android, haven't verified other environments

Comment: Where did you place the custom direct update code? Which authentication did you implement?